# Acquire tuple element in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a nested tuple as follows:

```
a = (((1, 2), 2), 3)
```

I know we could use `a[0][0][1]` to acquire the second element 2. However, this method might be inefficient with a long tuple. Is there any more efficient way to acquire the tuple element in this case?

Comment: there's nothing more efficient than accessing it by index

Comment: *"this method might be inefficient with a long tuple"* - might it? Why? Is there a specific performance problem you've experienced?

Comment: You need more efficiency than O(1) for each of the indexing operations? Interesting...

Comment: I mean, do I need to use a[0]....[1], if the element length of a is 100?

Comment: Do you mean _efficient_ or _easy to type_?

Comment: @exteralvictor why do you have such a deeply nested tuple anyway? There's ways to make accessing nested elements more *convenient* but not more *efficient*....

Comment: What is your goal in terms of accessing? What is the criteria for this lookup? Do you always know where the index is all the time? Because explicit index lookup is O(1). You don't get better than that.

Comment: @JonClements how convenient? Deeply nested turple is because I have a group of multiple parameters to add in each loop.

Comment: Are you sure a nested tuple is appropriate for that? It'd be quite odd if it was... however, unless you provide more detail - it's difficult to say....

Comment: @JohnGordon I just don’t know how to access the second element when the nested turple has 100 or more elements.

Comment: Why do you have such a data structure? Did you create this yourself? What is the main problem you are trying to solve that lead you to get to this type of data structure?

Comment: Avoiding a nested tuple is probably the simplest starting point.... if you always know it's N many levels deep and want to directly access a certain element, then don't have it that many levels deep?

Comment: @JonClements thank you mate, I will reconsider using list maybe. Probably a better idea.

Comment: in terms of accessing the element, `list` v/s `tuple` won't make much difference. In fact, since tuple as immutable, accessing it will be little more efficient. You need to share more information on your use-case with the example, then may be we would be able to help more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to do this dynamically and know that your indices are valid you can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to write this compactly:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda it, idx: it[idx], [0, 0, 1], a)  # returns 2
```

Comment: Good, a new thought. Thx Alex.

Answer (score 4):

You may write function for access tuple value

```
a = (((1, 2), 2), 3)
def access(obj, indexes):
    a = obj
    for i in indexes:
       try: 
           a = a[i]
       except IndexError:
           return None
       # except TypeError:
           # when you try to index deeper than the object supports

    # a  is not constrained to be a scalar, it may still be dimensional
    # if insufficient indexes were passed.
    return a  
print(access(a,(0,0,0)))
print(access(a,(0,0)))
```

Output

> 1
>
> (1, 2)

Comment: What's the point of having a function here? Just to access value based on index? How is `access(a,(0,0,0))` better than `a[0][0][0]`?

Comment: its just mean, index replacement is this function